# Putting 7 bits to a byte using loop

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I'm trying to put 7 bits to a byte (bit by bit) by using a loop:

```
unsigned char bytetosend;
unsigned char y[] = { 0x7f };
int x = 0;
int i;

int main()
{
    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        bytetosend = (y[x] & 0x01);
        bytetosend >>= 1;
        y[x] >>= 1;
    }
    printf("the out is %x", bytetosend);
}
```

but why is the output 0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you are "copying" the LSB of `y[x]` to the LSB of `bytetosend` and then you remove it by shifting `bytetosend` right by one.

I don't know why you need to copy bit by bit if you just can copy the whole byte at once by `bytetosend = y[x];` but let's assume that you really want it.

Then you can do it by:

```
bytetosend = 0;
for (i=0; i < 8; ++i)
{
    bytetosend |= y[x] & ((unsigned char)1 << i);
}
```

Comment: so  i can fix that by shifting lift? of bytetosend ?

Comment: @SalmaKHaled not really, by shifting left you will end up with the LSB of `y[x]` at the MSB of the `bytetosend`. See my edited post.

Comment: Recommend `(unsigned char)(1 << i)` ==> `((unsigned char)1 << i)`

Comment: @WeatherVane Can you explain why? For me it seems the same... Maybe on some CPU architectures this casting will take additional opcode.... but not sure you meant it...

Comment: Minor, but it is better to ensure the type is unsigned *before* it is shifted.

Comment: @SalmaKHaled if this is the best answer, please "accept" it by checking that box.

Comment: @WeatherVaneIn this case it has no impact at all but I accept it as a general code writing tip. Will be edited.